# Can 1 html calls 2 different controller from 2 different external javascript?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have my html..

```
<body ng-app="BuyBye">
<div id='welcomeBanner' ng-controller="1stController">

</div>


<div id="inputCtrl" ng-controller="2ndController">

</div>
```

Then I have 2 different javascript, one for 1stController

```
var app = angular.module('BuyBye', [])
app.controller('1stController', function($scope) {}
```

and one for 2ndController.

```
var app = angular.module('BuyBye', [])
app.controller('2ndController', function($scope) {}
```

But only 1 controller works while the other don't.
Is it because I have two separate JS files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you are defining module `BuyBye` twice. Instead you should define only once.

```
var app = angular.module('BuyBye', [])


var app = angular.module('BuyBye', [])
app.controller('1stController', function($scope) {});

app.controller('2ndController', function($scope) {});
```